# Using range slider to change HSL background color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I'm trying to use a range slider to edit the background color, but it isn't working, where am I going wrong here:

My range slider:

```
<input id="ex2" name="ex2' type="range" min="0" max="360" step="1" />
```

And my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var slider = document.getElementById("ex2");

$(slider).on('input', function () {

    var hue = $(this).val();

    var hsl = 'hsl('+ hue +', 50%, 50%)';

    console.log(hsl);

$(body).css({'background-color' : hsl });

});

});
```

Also here:

https://jsfiddle.net/oqt1vhmj/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uc582g9b/2/

Answer (score 1):

Did you check console for any errors?

Just fixed a small typo and all works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var slider = document.getElementById("ex2");

    $(slider).on('input', function () {

        var hue = $(this).val();

        var hsl = 'hsl('+ hue +', 50%, 50%)';

        console.log(hsl);

        $('body').css({'background-color' : hsl });
        //  ^--- typo here

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle isn't running because you need to change the resource from which you get the jQuery library. (error on *ReferenceError: $ is not defined"*)

I added a different resource, for example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it runs fine!

**here is the fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/noq2zd4f/8/